# Fit distribution based on total observation count but partial (upper) range

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I want to fit a normal distribution to empirical data, of which I only have a partial (upper) range of observations, and the total amount of observations. 
Example:

```
sort(-rnorm(1000), decreasing = T)[1:300]
```

where I know that the total number of observations is 1000, but I do not the mean, and preferably also not the kurtosis.

The percentile of observations can vary, and I accept a loss of accuracy with small data sets.

From the returned values, combined with the total number of observations, I want to recover the (closest fit to) original distribution.

I think the solution involves some kind of partial maximum likelood estimation, and although I know the concept of maximum likelihood, I do not know how to implement it in practice.

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know that you have complete data on the top 30% (X%) of the distribution? Or you have partial data more generally?

Comment: the percentage of complete data should be able to vary, so I need a general solution. Though I do know the percentage in each case of course as x/n. I have updated the question.